# Pandas- How to create a nested if condition Excel like row logic

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to check every row of columns A,B,C,D,E,F whether they are >200 or not, if not return the same value in a new column:

```
=IF(A2>200,IF(B2>200,IF(C2>200,IF(D2>200,IF(E2>200,F2,E2),D2),C2),B2),A2)
```

Condition:

Check if A2 cell value > 200

- If it is `True`, go to cell B2 check if the value > 200 and so on till E2.
- If it is `False`, give me value of A2 in a new column.

Finally after checking all the A,B,C,D,E,F rows for the > 200 condition, a new column is to be created.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your pandas DataFrame using `df.head().to_dict()`, any code that you have tried, and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? But check the real column names in pandas dataframe.

```
def function(df):
    
    if df['A1'] > 200:
        if df['B2'] > 200:
            if df['C2'] > 200:
                if df['D2'] > 200:
                    if df['E2'] > 200:
                        return df['F2']
                    else:
                        return df['E2']
                else:
                    return df['D2']
            else:
                return df['C2']
        else:
            return df['B2']
    else:
        return df['A2']
    
df['New_Column'] = df.apply(function, axis = 1)
```